# Why can't I pass the location of a static image file from my Django view to my html file using jinja templating?

Tags: html, django, django-views, jinja2, src

I'm trying to add an image to an HTML page by passing the name of the .jpg file to an html jinja template from a view. The image is located in a static folder, and will appear as desired if the file name is coded directly, but not when I try to pass it in through Jinja.

Django view code:

```
def page(request):

   location = '''src="{% static 'image.jpg' %}"'''

   return(render(request, 'page.html', {'location':location})
```

Code on HTML page:

```
{% load static %}

<img {{location}} alt="image">
```

The image file is located in a static folder at the root of the Django project

I've also tried other combinations of string to be passed in and HTML including:

```
location = '''"{% static 'image.jpg' %}"'''
<img src={{location}} alt="image"> 

location = "'image.jpg'"
<img src= "{% static {{location}} %}" alt="image">
```

When I code the file name in directly as follows:

```
<img src= "{% static "image.jpg" %}" alt="image">
```

the image is presented as desired.

I feel like there is something I'm misunderstanding, but I'm not sure what. I couldn't find another question asking how to do this when I searched, so please forgive me if you know of an answer I didn't find!

Answer (score 1):

OK... so this works:

```
location = "\image.jpg"

<img src= "{% static location %}" alt="things">
```

That extra slash at the start of the location variable name was what was missing! Can't believe it was that simple.